# No Plugins available in QGIS on Mac

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-3, mac, plugins

I downloaded the 3.10 version of QGIS onto my Mac (version 10.15.6). There are no Plugins available in the programme. Do I have to download plugins from somewhere else?

Also, in the Raster Menu, the only 2 options I have are Raster Calculator & Align Rasters, no other options. I'd like to build a virtual raster.

Comment: Plugins are available through the Plugins> Manage and install plugins. If you do not have that menu you might be missing Python support. How did you install QGIS?

Comment: When I click on that option a window comes up saying "No QGIS plugins found in /Applications/QGIS.3.10.app/ Contents/MacOS/plugins/ QGIS"

Comment: I installed QGIS through this link https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's two screenshots of a fresh install of QGIS Long Term Release version 3.10.10-A Coruña (downloaded from https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html on 2020-10-19) showing a default Plugin menu and Raster menu:

[image]

[image]

QGIS should be able to install the plugins itself from within the Plugins/Manage and Install Plugins menu option.  If that's not working, perhaps the install didn't work properly.